# Is Memory Layout for a class successive?

Tags: c++, class, static, memory-management

When we declare object of a class **is its memory layout successive**(One after the other)?If its successive than does **padding** occurs in it (like structure padding)?Please help me out with the concepts of **memory layout for a class**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you rephrase your title and question. and instead of using the phrase *"memory allocation"*, use *"memory layout"* if you mean so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When we declare object of a class is
>   its memory allocation successive(One
>   after the other)?

The Standard doesn't give any such guarantee. Object memory layout is implementation-defined.

Usually, memory address for data members increases in the order they're defined in the class . But this order may be disrupted at any place where the access-specifiers (`private`, `protected`, `public`) are encountered. This has been discussed in great detail in [Inside the C++ Object Model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545) by **Lippman**.

An excerpt from [C/C++ Users Journal](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill14.htm),

> The compiler isn't allowed to do this
>   rearrangement itself, though. The
>   standard requires that all data that's
>   in the **same** public:, protected:, or
>   private: must be laid out in that
>   order by the compiler. **If you
>   intersperse your data with access
>   specifiers, though, the compiler is
>   allowed to rearrange the
>   access-specifier-delimited blocks of
>   data to improve the layout**, *which is
>   why some people like putting an access
>   specifier in front of every data
>   member*.

Interesting, isn't it?

Comment: I find this hard to believe. If that were true how would code from two compilers interop?

Comment: @David: It doesn't. Practically the only way to have interoperability between compilers is to stick with plain old C.

Comment: @Tomek: pretty much spot on--though since most developers on a particular platform use the same compiler (or the same compiler, different versions), it's usually moot. Most Windows developers use VC++, most *NIX developers use GCC, etc.

Comment: @Tomek Seems pretty lame to me. It's hard to see why the standards committee would want to allow the generality of non-contiguous memory layout.

Comment: @David: actually it could interop if both follow the same ABI, like, for example, the Itanium ABI. But there is so much left to optimizations possibilities that in practice even with the same compiler a mere difference of flags (like packing) can prevent compatibility.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think even in C, the compiler is allowed to add padding between members of a struct (although I don't think it happens too often in practice). But correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @David, @Tomek, @Jonathan, @Matthieu and @riviera: I added an excerpt from C/C++ Journal to my answer. Check it out. :-