# Besides accessibility, what else access-specifiers effects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, public, protected

Besides the normal explenation of being visible or not to derived classes, is their any other difference?

If you make it more visible, is it taking more or less memory, does it slow thing down or...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the accessibility of members outside or to the derived classes, access specifiers might affect the object layout.

Quoting from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842434/is-memory-layout-for-a-class-successive/4842474#4842474):

Usually, memory address for data members increases in the order they're defined in the class . But **this order may be disrupted at any place where the access-specifiers (`private`, `protected`, `public`) are encountered**. This has been discussed in great detail in [Inside the C++ Object Model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545) by **Lippman**.

An excerpt from [C/C++ Users Journal](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill14.htm),

> The compiler isn't allowed to do this
>   rearrangement itself, though. The
>   standard requires that all data that's
>   in the **same** public:, protected:, or
>   private: must be laid out in that
>   order by the compiler. **If you
>   intersperse your data with access
>   specifiers, though, the compiler is
>   allowed to rearrange the
>   access-specifier-delimited blocks of
>   data to improve the layout**, *which is
>   why some people like putting an access
>   specifier in front of every data
>   member*.

Interesting, isn't it?

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, interresting. Thus if you need highly optimized code you'd better use indivudual access specifiers?

Comment: @Nawaz: And thanks, last time as it's too fast and too much. Am anyway thankfull to anyone who helped whomever. I must be a newby noob at stackoverflow.

Comment: @RealmSeeker: Yeah. That article suggests that. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: this is slightly incorrect. I'll answer in greater details because comments are not really suitable for such an explanation.

Comment: @Nawaz: here you go, I've excavated the quote from the latest version of the C++0X FCD. Note the absence of "block" notion, it does not matter if you repeat the access specifier before each member or intersperse public/private blocks in your declaration.

Comment: @Matthieu: that is C++0x, not C++03. But thanks for mentioning that. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't have the C++03 standard unfortunately, and I have no intention of paying for it now :) I doubt it changed lately, I'd rather think the quote is ill-conceived and doesn't perfectly convey what the author meant.

Comment: @Matthieu: What do you mean by "ill-conceived"?

Comment: @Nawaz: I mean that it may not express what the author really wanted to say (on the other hand, we don't generally speak "legalese", unambiguous and extremely carefully worded sentences being reserved to texts the like of the Standard). It may also be that the author is wrong or that the Standard changed, but since I don't have the C++03 version, we'll have to wait for a more informed fellow to come :)

Comment: Access specifiers do *not* affect visibility.  Access specifiers affect accessibility.

Comment: @Fred: Is there any difference between these words, in *this* context? By *visibility* I mean the same thing which you meant by *accessibility*.

Comment: @Fred: What does that mean? :-/

Comment: What does "yes" mean? The rest is required by SO because comments cannot be shorter than 15 chars.  Or did you mean something else because you edited the earlier comment?

Comment: If you mean "accessibility", why don't you say "accessibility" instead of using the wrong word?

Comment: @Fred: Actually, your "yes" explains nothing. What is the difference?

Comment: @Fred: What do *visibility* could mean in this context?

Comment: If you want to say "what is the difference", then say that instead of "is there any difference" :) Inaccessible members are still visible.  Overloads are a good example because that's where you can actually hide members: a derived method hides a base method of the same name.

Answer (score 3):

From `n3225`, **9.2 [class.mem]** *note 15*

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (11).

This means that given the following declaration:

```
class Foo {
public:  int a;
private: int b;
public:  int c;
private: int d;
};
```

Only the following assertions are enforced by the standard:

```
Foo foo;

assert(&foo.a < &foo.c);
assert(&foo.b < &foo.d);
```

@Nawaz's citation can be interpreted as giving 4 blocks that can be freely intermixed, but this is not the case. The declaration of `Foo` is perfectly equivalent to:

```
class Foo' {
public:  int a,c;
private: int b,d;
};
```

Indeed the compiler completely ignores (for this purpose) whether a specifier appeared once or multiple times, and specifying it each time is spurious and at best slows the compilation down because of the extra parsing. For a human reader, it might be clearer... but this is highly subjective.