# A way to disable conversion operators?

Tags: c++

Is there any way to disable the conversion operator of a class?  Assume it is a library class and I cannot modify the source code (or headers). I sometimes encounter a library that thinks to be clever and defines conversions which are silly and sometimes just dangerous.

For example, given this declaration in a header which I cannot modify:

```
class TooClever
{
   ...
public:
   operator char const*();
};
```

Is there any way (trickery allowed, even if compiler specific) I can prevent this operator from ever being used in my code?

Comment: You say you cannot modify the header - why? Just remove the operator. Since they're not virtual functions, just remove them. It won't break anything. That's not guaranteed by the standard, but I have yet to see a case where it doesn't hold.

Comment: The headers belong to an external library, meaning they're not part of the same repository. So I could change the header on my machine, but other machines wouldn't have the change. Even if I did change any update to that library might overwrite the changes. So while an option, it is one that can easily become lost.

Comment: Are you developing an open source project? If not I don't see the problem: just add the library to your repository and commit the patch. When updating you would have to repeat the change of course, but you usually don't update dependencies all that often (at least at my company we don't).

Comment: Like I said, it is an option, but isn't simple.  In one case we compile the library from source, so we'd first have to compile without the patch, and then patch only the installed file. And that script would have to work cross-platform. I mean, we have patches for some code already, but I was hoping for an easier to maintain solution.

Comment: You could "#ifdef" the operator to avoid having to replace the file after compiling the library. You would only have to add a #define when compiling the library. But I agree, it isn't particularly pretty. Unfortunately I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 3):

Create your own descendant, add `operator char const*()` to it, but make it private. While still present, this ensures it can't be called accidentally (in fact, at all).

Comment: It won't work in this case. The *Clever API* returns these objects and many modules will work with them directly or just as temporaries being passed to another function.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: you can have your descendant (which should inherit privately) providing an implicit constructor and casting operator to make it interchangeable with the Clever API's type, so it converts silently to your safe type as you accept it into your code, and coverts back to an unsafe type when you call existing unsafe functions.

Comment: It would not be able to catch the case of `myFunc( cleverFunc() )` with a signature of `void myFunc( char const * )`.  This is actually quite common in the code (just using temporaries).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible.

Conversion operators are nothing but functions. So what you're essentially asking is disabling a function which is simply not possible. Disabling `operator int()` in the following class is conceptually equivalent to disabling  `fun` function.

```
class A
{
 public:
    operator int(); //want to disable it?
    void fun(); //can you disable it?
};

A a;
a.fun(); //can you make the compiler generate error at this line?
int i = a; //can you make the compiler generate error at this line also?
```

Can you make the compiler generate error at the indicated lines? No.

---

EDIT:

Derivation is a different thing. Derivation is not disabling; its redefinition in the inaccessible section.  And that too, inaccessible from outside. The member functions and friends can always access them!

Comment: Yes and no. In the global scope you can certainly override and block access to functions by giving different overrides, or using a template that matches better. I also believe it isn't possible, but perhaps somebody has a clever trick -- or perhaps a compiler specific extension.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- Your compiler supports [explicit conversion operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicit_conversion_operators),
- The `TooClever` class only exposes conversion operators,
- The trickery allowed includes macros,

You can make the conversion operators explicit by doing:

```
#define operator explicit operator
#include <tooclever.h>
#undef operator
```

Comment: Dangerous! That can harm other part of the header. Never do it.

Comment: `#undef operator` -- does it impact all the other included headers after this line?

Comment: The header is not usually included directly, but buried within a chain of headers.  I'd also be worried here that since the declaration is altered the class may not be compatible with the one in the shared library (though usually they aren't virtual, so it might be safe)

Comment: @Nawaz, you're absolutely right, it's dangerous and even *evil* to do that. I would never do it in the general case, but trickery is explicitly allowed here and that *might* solve the questioner's problem :)

Comment: @RouMao, the headers included after the `#undef` should be safe.

Comment: @edA-qa, I don't think switching from implicit to explicit conversion operators would impact binary compatibility (but I did not test it). However, if you don't include the header directly, my strategy probably won't work.

Comment: @RouMao: it's the other headers included by `<tooclever.h>` that are the problem: they'll be mangled too.  If you could include them earlier, then the include guards / #pragma once should make it safe, but there's no general, maintainable way to sync the list of files `<tooclever.h>` includes.

Comment: You can use this trick to check the operators are not used,but you don't have to keep it for release once the check is done.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a private copy of this header file. Then change the

```
class TooClever
{
   ...
private:  // make it private
   operator char const*(); 
public:   // change back to public
   ...
};
```

Put the file folder into your include path, make it ahead the 3rd library include path.

Comment: It might produce incompatible binaries, [because access-specifiers might affect object layout.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978302/besides-accessibility-what-else-access-specifiers-effects)

Comment: @Nawaz I think the C++ linker should resolve all the member functions in the link library. And all they have been compiled.

Comment: Your modification would require re-compiling source (.cpp) file.

Comment: you can use this only when you want to detect the operator use, and not all the time, then you avoid the incompatible binaries problem. you don't need to run the "detection" version.

Answer (score 0):

I think deriving the class will be the best idea, with some **trickery**:

```
class DontThinkSo : public TooClever
{
   // put proper constructor calls if needed
private:
   operator char const*();
};

#define TooClever DontThinkSo  // replace all instances by derived class
```